# Frage zu Pluralbildung: viele kombinatorische(n) Optimierungsprobleme(n)

Tags: grammar

Ich habe Schwierigkeiten mit dem folgenden Satz:

> Komplexitätstheoretisch gehören viele kombinatorische**n** Optimierungsprobleme zur Klasse der NP-schweren Probleme.

Wie sagt man es richtig?

> viele kombinatorische Probleme

oder

> viele kombinatorische**n** Probleme

Was ist mit dem **n** am Ende des Wortes Probleme(n)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das *n* am Ende von *Probleme* wäre falsch, weil weder das Plural Genitiv   (in „zur Klasse der NP-schweren Probleme“) noch Nominativ im Plural (in *kombinatorische Optimierungsprobleme*) ein solches *n* benötigen.

Die Deklination nach *viele* ist [schwankend](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwankend.html#Anchor-Nach-49575) und wird in diesem Fall von

> Nach dem flektierten Adjektiv *viel-* wird ein zweites Adjektiv gleich flektiert wie *viel-*. (aus derselben Quelle).

beschrieben. In deinem Fall richtig wäre also *viele kombinatorische Optimierungsprobleme*. Mit bestimmten Artikel wäre *die viele**n** kombinatorische**n** Optimierungsprobleme* richtig.

Comment: Die Antwort ist richtig, aber die kombinatorischen Probleme sind aber kein Genitiv, sondern Nominativ.

Comment: Aufgrund des Kontexts glaube ich auch, dass es hier tatsächlich um die Optimierungsprobleme geht. Vorschlag zur Formulierung: Der Nominativ (im) Plural.

Comment: @Robert Gut, ich hoffe mit dem Edit ist schon klar, worauf ich mich bezogen habe. Danach habe ich auch das mit Optimierungsproblem (nach Maasumis Vorschlag) hinzugefügt.

Comment: Ich hoffe, du hast keine Probleme mit meinem Edit, der etwas Klarheit hinzufügt, die ich vorher vermisst habe. ;)

Comment: Gar keines, ganz im Gegenteil : )